# put function-documentation fails inside own function

Tags: doc-strings

How is it that `(put 'workbench 'function-documentation` does not work inside `(defun workbench`?

```
(setq workbench-usage "Usage Information.")

(defun workbench (&optional prefix name mode)
  "Make new temporary buffer.

NAME  A title given to a specific buffer.
MODE  Language mode for programming or markup text. \n\n"

  (interactive "p")

  (put 'workbench 'function-documentation
       (concat (documentation 'workbench t) workbench-usage)) )
```

Comment: It does work.  If I execute `(workbench)` then `(get 'workbench 'function-documentation)` tells me the right thing.  Note that the whole `put` form is not evaluated until the function is executed!!!

Comment: You are correct.  If I run `workbench`, then do `C-h f workbench`, the usage gets printed.  Is there any way so solve the impasse, so that the usage gets displayed even if the function has not been executed yet?

Comment: Sure: do yr documentation thing *after* defining `workbench`!  However, I must say that this is a lot of work just to avoid having a long docstring and I cannot really see the point of the enterprise.  I think having the documentation all in one place (the usual place) is way "cleaner" than what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: It all depends how long the documentation is.  Then the usual place is how it should be kept.

Comment: At this point I could make a function that takes the function name and the usage string.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP confirms that what he said doesn't work actually works. (Comments should not be used to try to migrate/evolve what's being asked.)